# SCNView Re-sizing Issue

Tags: cocoa, scenekit

I am trying to render 3D bar chart in SCNView using ScreenKit framework.

My rendering code is,

```
int height=10,y=0,x=0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    SCNBox *box1 = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:4 height:height length:2 chamferRadius:0];
    boxNode1 = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:box1];
    boxNode1.position = SCNVector3Make(x, y, 0);
    SCNMaterial *material = [SCNMaterial material];
    material.diffuse.contents  = (NSColor *)[self.colorArray objectAtIndex:i%6];
    material.specular.contents = [NSColor whiteColor];
    material.shininess = 1.0;
    box1.materials = @[material];
    //boxNode1.transform = rot;
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode1];
    x+=6;
    height+=10;
    y += 5 ;
}
```

I can render but while re-sizing the view the chart bars goes to the center of the view.

I need to render the chart, which cover the margins of the view and when Re-size it have to change accordingly.  The image(s) below shows my problem.

---

### Original Image:

[image]

---

### Image where less stretching of both windows:

[image]

Can anyone please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The the windows in the image that you had linked to in your original question was very stretched and that made it very hard to see what was going on. When I took that image and made the windows less stretched it was easier to have some idea of what is going on.

I think that you are seeing a general resizing issue. Either you are using springs and struts and have configured flexible margins on the left and right or you are using auto layout with a centered view with fixed width.

I assume that the red boxes that I have drawn in the image below is the bounds of your scene view in both these cases. You can easily see if this is the case by giving the scene view a different background color and resize it again.

My solution to your problem would be to change how your view resizes as the window resizes, to better meet your expectations.

[image]